# What is the purpose of the pressure relief door fitted on the PW1127G-JM engines of the A320NEO?

Tags: jet-engine, airbus-a320

[image: pressure relief door[![]]Hey guys many times during my exterior walkaround I noticed on the A320NEOs that they have this pressure relief door and our SOP for the exterior walkaround states to check that this door is closed. However I would like to know what is the purpose of this door? As it's not mentioned in the FCOM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the nacelle cavity of a turbofan engine and in the casing of the engine core, there are different zones or closed compartments used for ventilation/cooling and in the case of the nacelle lip, also for anti-icing (see the first two images below). If a highly-pressurised duct (such as the anti-ice inlet duct shown in the 3rd image) bursts, the pressure builds up to a dangerous level, despite the ventilation exits. To prevent structural damage to these closed compartments, pressure relief doors are installed which are triggered automatically.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Edit: my first answer lacked some details, so I rewrote it.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Is it more clear now?

Comment: Yes, that is great, thanks very much. I will delete my previous comment (and also this one, later). Cheers.

Comment: Is this specific to the PW engine? The door is a thrust reverser pressure relief door as per the FCOM.

Comment: Pressure relief doors are definitely not specific to the PW engine. Even, it seems like in other engines, they are also used for the thrust reverser compartment (zone 3). Check out this discussion: https://www.pprune.org/archive/index.php/t-403785.html